# Ciclo anidado con for en C

Tags: c

Es posible realizar esta impresion(imagen) con dos ciclos anidados for?:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que llevo, hay dos variables que generan números aleatorios, una es para generar los números que se van y la otra variable el numero de caracteres. La pregunta es que como llego a imprimir el numero de caracteres. Ya que con mi código solo imprime un solo carácter y no lo del numero especificado.

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int numerosPorGenerar = rand()%20 + 5, numAleatorio = rand()%30 + 1;
char caracter = '$';

printf("Numeros generados: %d\n",numerosPorGenerar);

for (int i = 0; i < numerosPorGenerar ; i++)
{
numAleatorio = rand()%30 + 1 ;
printf("%d \t %c\n",numAleatorio , caracter );


}
return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si es posible con un ciclo for para cada línea de información y adentro de ese ciclo for realizas otro for que repite el carácter según el valor del número aleatorio.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int numerosPorGenerar = rand()%20 + 5, numAleatorio;
char caracter = '$';

printf("Numeros generados: %d\n",numerosPorGenerar);

for (int i = 0; i < numerosPorGenerar ; i++)
{
numAleatorio = rand()%30 + 1 ;
printf("%d \t ",numAleatorio);

for (int j = 0; j < numAleatorio ; j++){
printf("%c",caracter );    
}
printf("\n");  

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solo faltó mencionar que debería agregar `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Cierto, gracias no tome en cuenta el cambio de renglón "\n" para la impresión, quería hacer toda la impresión en un solo printf, gracias Claudio.

Comment: Respecto a lo #include <stdio.h>, si lo tengo en mi código pero no lo copie aquí, de todas maneras gracias por la observación, Mateo.